# PDFminer in Python

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I downloaded the pdfminer, the commandline methods work perfectly but I want to be able to convert multiple pdf documents at the same time so I am trying to use the pdfminer as a library, I found this os stackoverflow but I can't get it to work..

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from cStringIO import StringIO



def convert_pdf(path):

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)

    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, fp)
    fp.close()
    device.close()

    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    print str


convert_pdf("/Users/gorkemyurtseven/Desktop/casino.pdf")
```

when I run it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdfminer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf
  File "/Users/gorkemyurtseven/Desktop/pdfminer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf
ImportError: No module named pdfinterp
```

Comment: Does `import pdfminer` produce a similar `ImportError`? Possibly pdfminer is not on your python path. If so, you might need to run `python setup.py install` from the pdfminer directory.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are calling your script `pdfminer` as the module and it goes crazy when trying to import a module with the same name.

Another reasons may be that `pdfminer` module is installed incorrectly or it is not the correct version for your python distribution.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141670/2445273) post, the problem is that your file is named `pdfminer.py`.
Change the name and delete `__pycache__/` directory and  `pdfminer.pyc` file that are created:

```
$ rm -r __pycache__/ pdfminer.pyc
$ mv pdfminer.py mypdfminer.py
```