# pdfminer - ImportError: No module named pdfminer.pdfdocument

Tags: python, pdfminer

I am trying to install pdfMiner to work with CollectiveAccess. My host (pair.com) has given me the following information to help in this quest:

> When compiling, it will likely be necessary to instruct the
>   installation to use your account space above, and not try to install
>   into the operating system directories. Typically, using "--
>   home=/usr/home/username/pdfminer" at the end of the install    command
>   should allow for that.

I followed this instruction when trying to install. 
The result was:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts
changing mode of /usr/home/username/pdfminer/bin/latin2ascii.py to 755
changing mode of /usr/home/username/pdfminer/bin/pdf2txt.py to 755
changing mode of /usr/home/username/pdfminer/bin/dumppdf.py to 755
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/home/username/pdfminer/lib/python/pdfminer-20140328.egg-info
Writing /usr/home/username/pdfminer/lib/python/pdfminer-20140328.egg-info
```

I don't see anything wrong with that (I'm very new to python), but when I try to run the sample command `$ pdf2txt.py samples/simple1.pdf` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "pdf2txt.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument ImportError: No module named pdfminer.pdfdocument
```

I'm running python 2.7.3. I can't install from root (shared hosting). The most recent version of pdfminer, which is 2014/03/28.
I've seen some posts on similar issues ("no module named. . . " but nothing exactly the same. The proposed solutions either don't help (such as installing with sudo - not an option; specifying the path for python (which doesn't seem to be the issue), etc.).

Or is this a question for my host? (i.e., something amiss or different about their setup)

Comment: install the package using 'pip install pdfminer.six'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the package `pdfminer` is installed to a non-standard/non-default location, Python won't be be able to find it. In order to use it, you will need to add it to your 'pythonpath'. Three ways:

1. At run time, put this in your script `pdf2txt.py`:

   ```
   import sys
   # if there are no conflicting packages in the default Python Libs =>
   sys.path.append("/usr/home/username/pdfminer")
   ```

   or

   ```
   import sys
   # to always use your package lib before the system's =>
   sys.path.insert(1, "/usr/home/username/pdfminer")
   ```

   **Note:** The install path specified with `--home` is used as the Lib for all packages which you might want to install, not just this one. You should delete that folder and re-install with `--
   home=/usr/home/username/myPyLibs` (or any generic name) so that when you install other packages with that install path, you would only need the one path to add to your local Lib to be able to import them:

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(1, "/usr/home/username/myPyLibs")
   ```
2. Add it to PYTHONPATH before executing your script:

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/home/username/myPyLibs"
   ```

   And then put that in your `~/.bashrc` file (`/usr/home/username/.bashrc`) or `.profile` as applicable. This may not work for programs which are not executed from the console.
3. Create a [VirtualEnv and install the packages](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) you need to that.

Answer (score 14):

use this command worked for me and removed the error

> ```
> pip install pdfminer.six
> ```

Answer (score 10):

I had an error like this:

```
No module named 'pdfminer.pdfinterp'; 'pdfminer' is not a package
```

My problem was that I had named my script `pdfminer.py` which for the reasons that I don't know, Python took it for the original `pdfminer` package files and tried to compiled it.

I *renamed* my script to something else, deleted all the `*.pyc` file and `__pycache__` directory and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have a virtual environment and I had to activate it before I did a pip3 install to have the venv see it.

```
source ~/venv/bin/activate
```