# pdfminer - import error

Tags: python, pdfminer

I’m new to Python and programming in general.

I am trying to install pdfMiner.  I have Windows 7 with Python 2.7 installed. 
I followed the instructions when installing (downloaded the PDFMiner source, unpacked it, and ran `setup.py` to install and it was installed in `C:\pdfminer`) – no errors.

It created:
`build`, `build\lib,build\lib\pdfminer`, then copied files to `build\lib\pdfminer`. It created `build\scripts-2.7` and copied `tools\pdf2txt.py`, `dymppdf.py` to `scripts`, then wrote `install-egg-info`
and had no errors with install.

When I try running the test document from the command line:

```
C:\pdfminer\pdfminer-20140328> pdf2txt.py samples/simple1.pdf
```

I get:

```
File “C:\Python27\Scripts\pdf2txt.py”, line3, in <module> from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
ImportError:  No module named pdfminer.pdfdocument
```

I saw this post:

[pdfminer - ImportError: No module named pdfminer.pdfdocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904738/pdfminer-importerror-no-module-named-pdfminer-pdfdocument)

and tried following it (#1..put `sys.path.append…` into `pdf2txt.py`) and get the same error.

The system variables do include the path  (`pdfminer\pdfminer-20140328`).

I’ve looked for other solutions but haven’t had much luck – the file is there but I can’t seem to get the program to look in the right area for it…I think.

Do I have the wrong path or is it installed in the wrong directory?