# Python - PDFMiner (Error - Module PDFdocument missing)

Tags: python-3.x, pdfminer

Facing the below error, when I try to execute the sample code given in Basic Usage of [Link](https://euske.github.io/pdfminer/programming.html):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:/TestPy/Test/readPDF.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfminer.pdfdocument'
```

I checked these 2 links - [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783099/pdfminer-import-error) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904738/pdfminer-importerror-no-module-named-pdfminer-pdfdocument) but was unable to figure it out.

But when I checked the github page - [Link](https://github.com/jaepil/pdfminer3k/tree/master/pdfminer) I notice that PDFdocument.py itself is missing. Also when I download from pdfminer3k 1.3.1 from [Link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k/1.3.1) even this does not have that.

Is the error due to missing PDFdocument in the package itself? or am I doing something wrong?